# sqlite3 and with statement - do I need it without cursor?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to understand why to use with (context manager) in sqlite3.

As far as I know `with` will automatically commit changes, but only when cursor will be created like:

```
 cursor = connection.cursor()
```

but in sqlite3 I can directly execute with connection itself like:

```
connection.execute("SQL")
#then 
connection.commit()
```

to make changes without cursor.

I though that context manager will close connection automatically after but its not.
So do I need to use `with` statement if I am not creating `cursor` in `sqlite3` ?

Also I didn't observed any differences if I don't use `connection.close()` at the end, can I check somehow open connections?

Edit:

```
with slite3.connection('my_db.db") as connection:
    connection.execute("SQL")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

# so in example above if I am not using cursor I just can do:

connection = sqlite3.connection('my_db.db")
connection.execute("SQL")
connection.commit()
connection.close()
# Its the same?
```

Comment: [`connection.execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute) creates a cursor and returns it. Calling `connection.commit` commits *any* pending changes, no matter what cursor may have been used to execute the command that made the change.

Answer (score 1):

It is true using with statment in SQLite will commit changes made after the block of code is exited. Although, this only happens when using cursor object to execute SQL commands.When executing SQL commands directly with the connection object, changes must be committed explicitly using connection.commit(). It is recommended to use cursor the with statement to ensure that the connection is properly closed after the code block is executed. To check if a connection has an open transaction, you can use sqlite3.Connection.in_transaction property. To see how many changes have been made on the connection since it was opened, you can use the sqlite3.Connection.total_changes property.

Comment: "It is recommended to use cursor the with statement to ensure that the connection is properly closed" so what does it mean? when I am using cursor in with statement I dont need to close cursor but only connection with `connection.close()` ? so like in docs if I am able to use `connection.execute()` without cursor I can just dont use with statement and go directly to close connection after all